# Asking rsync to create *any* necessary directories

Tags: files, rsync

I have the following loop in zsh:

```
 for x in my_folders*; 
 do 
   rsync -adrv $x/foo/bar/ /foo2/bar2/new_dir/$x/
 done
```

`new_dir` does not exist before calling `rsync`, and I would like `rsync` to create it, along with everything else needed for the copy operation.

I am passing `rsync` the flags `d` and `r` but it complains with:

```
rsync: mkdir "/foo2/bar2/new_dir/item1" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

It apparently assumes that the folders `/foo2/bar2/new_dir/$x/` exist prior to the copying, which don't. With this:

- Is there a way to ask rsync to create **any** necessary directories needed for the copy operation to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the `rsync` man page I don't see an option for your scenario. But what about adding the directory manually before starting the sync, thus avoiding your issue?

```
for x in my_folders*; 
do  
   mkdir -p "/foo2/bar2/new_dir/$x"
   rsync -adrv "$x/foo/bar/" "/foo2/bar2/new_dir/$x/"
done
```